# understanding about CDP p14, 0xE, c14, c14, c14, 7

Tags: arm, bootstrapping

I was reading one bootstrap applied on the ARM966E-S and I found this instruction

```
 CDP p14, 0xE, c14, c14, c14, 7
```

I have searched from the manual of this core processor but there is no information about this operation. At the same time I have googled but turned out to no result. I don't know what this instruction really means and can anyone explain it to me please? Thanks.

Comment: Given that that's the "disassembly" of 0xEEEEEEEE, I'm rather dubious as to whether it's _really_ an instruction.

Comment: It does be the disassembly of 0xEEEEEEEE.

Comment: Thanks, Notlikethat. It does be the disassembly of 0xEEEEEEEE. And one function calls it on some condition. I guess this bad instruction is only to trigger a undef exception. Now I can't debug it and once I figure out it I will notify you in this post.